# How to display icon in button's text

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC. My goal is to change the text of this button

```
<input type="submit" value="Save and Continue" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" />
```

From "Save and Continue" to "Saving... <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>" once the user clicks on it. I'm still in the process of searching for an answer, but what I'd like to do is change the text in the .click method using jQuery

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function () {

        //$("input[type='submit']").val("Saving... " + ?);
});
```

Is this possible to do? Is there an Html helper method to use? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></button>,
```

Initially it'll show the icon what you want or you may use the text as well.

In your jquery function, modify the innerHtml to the text along with the icon where as in the  type button you cannot display the icons.

JQuery changes:

```
$("button[type='submit']").click(function () {

    $(this).html("Saving... <i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\"></i>");
});
```

Comment: $("button[type='submit']").html('<p>your html goes here.</p>');

Comment: Can I still change the value from "Save and Continue" to "Saving... (icon)" ?

Comment: Yes, see by setting the inner html of the button tag you can modify.

Comment: However I am using an input tag, not a button tag. Can I interchange the two?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it to button tag since input tag accepts only values not html.